# typescript node insert on mongodb database

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

im a total newbie in js (typescript, mongoDB, node.)

i just found that my code is not behaving as i expected, im getting 6 registers on the mongoDB instead of just one, it should check if the register exists and then update it, i dont know if it is something related to the await / async or i am doing something wrong, thanks in advace, here is my code.

```
fields.forEach((value) => {
        
    try {

        const mongoConnection = new DocumentDbRepository();    
        let checksIfExists = await mongoConnection.getValue(key, information[uniqueValue]);

        if(checksIfExists==null){
            let insert = await mongoConnection.insertValue(information);
            console.log(insert);
        }
        
        if(checksIfExists?.passValue===information.passValue){
            
            console.log('---------update---------');

            let sons = Object.values(information.ticketToRide);
            information.ticketToRide = sons;
            let update = await mongoConnection.updateRegister(information, checksIfExists._id);
            console.log(update);

            
          
        } else {
            
            console.log('---------insert---------');
            
            let sons = Object.values(information.ticketToRide);
            information = sons;
            let insert = await mongoConnection.insertValue(information);
            console.log(insert);

        }

        

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}



async getValue(uniqueValue: any, keyValue:any) {

        if (this._connection == null) {
            await this.connect();
        }
        const db = this._connection.db(DocumentDbRepository.DbName);
        const ticketToRide = db.collection("ticketToRide");
        const query = {};
        query[uniqueValue] = ''+keyValue+'';
        const passInfo = await ticketToRide.findOne(query);
        
        return passInfo;

    }

   

    async insertValue(information: any) {

        if (this._connection == null) {
            await this.connect();
        }
        const db = this._connection.db(DocumentDbRepository.DbName);
        const ticketToRide = db.collection("ticketToRide");

        let check = await ticketToRide.insertOne(
            information
        )
        return check;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to create a connection inside the loop.

Second, mongodb has an update() or updateMany() method that has a special option `{ upsert: true }`. If it is passed, insert will happen automatically.

Usage example:

`Person.update( { name: 'Ted' }, { name: 'Ted', age : 50 }, { upsert: true })`